# How to paste copied text (captured in copy mode) to tmux's own command prompt?

Tags: tmux

When customizing `.tmux.conf` I often need to try the command on the fly so I want to copy commands from `.tmux.conf` (being opened in editor) to the command prompt (`<c-b> :`). I tried `<c-b> ]` after the command prompt but it does not work.

Comment: doesn't ctrl-y work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not possible to do without using the system clipboard (which assumes you're running a window manage of some sort).

I have this in my `.tmuxrc`:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard"
```

This means when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after selecting something in tmux, it's copied to the *system* clipboard.

Thereafter, in my terminal I can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste it into the terminal.

This should work for your use case, I think.

Comment: this works only if tmux is running on local server right?

Comment: no -- it assumes its running on your local workstation --- the `xclip` in particular, requires xwindows to also be running on that machine